# Stuck on implementing menu using Javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, z-index

I've got a table, and I wanted to use a table cell, so that when I click it, it'll open another menu table overlapping the original using the Z-index to do it. I've tried everything I can think of.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#weblinkbut').click(function(){
            $('.weblinkmenu').css('z-indez','9');       
    $('.menuhome').css('z-index','8');
 });
});
</script>
<table id="menuhome" class="menuhome" width="181" height="250" border="1" bordercolor="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="">
<tr>
    <td width="75" height="90" id="weblinkbut">
    <p><img src="../../Resources/test/images/weblinkicon.png" width="40" height="40"></p><p>Website link</p>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td width="75" height="90"><p><img src="../../Resources/test/images/phoneicon.png" width="40" height="40"/></p>
    <p>Phone Number</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="75" height="90"><p><img src="../../Resources/test/images/emailicon.jpg" width="40" height="40"></p>
    <p>Email address</p>
    </td>
    <td width="75" height="90"><p><img src="../../Resources/test/images/newdocicon.png" width="30" height="40">
<P>Plain Text</P> 
    </td>   
</tr>
 </table>

  <table id="weblinkmenu" class="weblinkmenu" width="181" height="250" border="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" bordercolor="#000000" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="">
  <tr>
  <td width="75" height="90"><p><img src="../../Resources/test/images/weblinkicon.png" width="40" height="40"></p>
  <p>Website link</p>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: $('.weblinkmenu').css('z-indez','9');   //change that z-indez to z-index...then explain ur pbm clearly..

Comment: When i view the webpage on the my local server, when i click on the table cell, it should drop the 'Menuhome' back a few z-index and bring up the appropriate menu (in this case it's the 'weblinkbut' i click on and want the 'weblinkmenu' to overlap the 'menuhome').

Comment: Still doesn't work when i change the typo "z-indez" to "z-index"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are missing is, that the tables are not positioned on top of each other.
You can for example achieve this by setting both tables `position` to absolute. Otherwise the `z-index` has no effect. Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uTLhX/.

If you position the tables like this you can drop the z-index and just toggle visibility, because later defined elements have higher z-index by default

Comment: .menuhome  { z-index:9; position:absolute; top:50px; left:50px; font:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; }

.weblinkmenu   { z-index:8; position:absolute; top:50px; left:50px; font:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center;  }

Comment: Soon as i put it in my doc and tried to test it. It doesn't work. I copy and paste exactly what was in the 'Fiddle'. I also tried it in a fresh doc and still nothing.

Comment: Then you should simplify your own code and check why it doesn't work... You could also add debug output to your javascript code to check if it working(like alert). One thing: Are you loading jquery in your page? Because the functions you used are from jquery

Comment: You Beautiful person! Thank you very much. Turns out as well my z-index for my content divs were clashing with the whole doc. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: $('#weblinkbut') instead of $('td#weblinkbut')

Comment: @ShibinRagh This is totally unnecessary, #weblinkbut selects the element with that id. Since ids are unique(should be at least) it works without perpending the td. You could have tried my fiddle and would have seen that it works...

Answer (score 0):

Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)